# Non const field fine in a function but recognised as const in another one

Tags: c++

I have a non const field ctxt.
And I have a funtion like this:

```
inventory_input inventory_selector::get_input()
{
    inventory_input res;

    const input_context ip;

    res.action = ctxt.handle_input();
    res.ch = ctxt.get_raw_input().get_first_input();

    std::tuple<point, bool> tuple = ctxt.get_coordinates_inventory( w_inv );//Fine
    std::tuple<point, bool> tuple = ip.get_coordinates_inventory( w_inv );//Error

    res.entry = find_entry_by_invlet( res.ch );

    if( res.entry != nullptr && !res.entry->is_selectable() ) {
        res.entry = nullptr;
    }

    return res;
}
```

the error is "the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function" as ip is const but the funtion get_coordinates_inventory is not const.
However, I have a nother funtion like this:

```
inventory_entry *inventory_selector::find_entry_by_coordinate( point coordinate ) const
{
    input_context ip;
    std::tuple<point, bool> tuple = ctxt.get_coordinates_inventory( w_inv );//surprising, this line is having error.
    std::tuple<point, bool> tuple = ip.get_coordinates_inventory( w_inv );//this line dosn't has error
}
```

The error message is:
the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "input_context_inventory" object type is: const input_context.
I cannot understand why is this happening, both ctxt and ip are non const how can one of them having error while another one doesn't?

Comment: please create a [MRE]

Comment: *both ctxt and ip are non const* No, `ip` is declared `const` in your code.

Comment: Please include the definition of `get_coordinates_inventory()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a non const field ctxt
>
> ...
>
> the funtion get_coordinates_inventory is not const

There is your problem.  Note the `const` qualifier on this method:

```
inventory_entry *inventory_selector::find_entry_by_coordinate( point coordinate ) const
                                                                                  ^^^^^
```

This means that this method can be invoked on a `const inventory_selector`.  Therefore, within this function the implicit `this` pointer points to `const inventory_selector`.  Because of this, you can't invoke a non-const method on `ctxt` -- it is also const since it is a member of an object that is considered const within the context of the method:

- `this` is `const inventory_selector *`.
- So `this->ctxt` is `const input_context &`.
- So the invocation `this->ctxt.get_coordinates_inventory()` is disallowed because that method is not declared const.

Either `inventory_selector::find_entry_by_coordinate` should be made non-const, or `input_context::get_coordinates_inventory` should be made const.